# C or Matlab row, column, array problem question

Tags: arrays, matlab

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrsKa.png)

```
     k=15;

     for i=1:k:length(aa)    % aa = 100
        for j=1:k:length(bb) % bb = 200
          result(j,i) = function(a, b, c, d)
        end
     end
```

I am trying to save the calculated value by extracting k by 15 steps.

If you do it this way, the next value will come out from the 1st row, 1st column, 16th row, 1st column, **as shown in the picture above**, and the value of 0 will come out in between.

So, I'm trying to write additional code that pulls them out in sequence like the right part of the picture...

```
     for ii = size_aa:-1:1
         if result(ii,:) == 0
             result(ii,:) = [];
         end
     end
```

I tried the method of removing zero elements, but it takes too much time. Is there any other way?

Comment: A better way? Don't create them... It is unclear what your code example does (please read [mre] to learn how to provide code), but I guess you could start with doing `result((j-1)/k+1, (i-1)/k+1) = function(...)`.

Comment: Why is this tagged with C? It's not C code...

Comment: Removing zero elements is as easy as doing: ```results(results == 0) = [];```

Comment: Please, remove the ```c``` tag, as the question is related to ```matlab```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have your `result` matrix, you can use `result(result == 0) = [];` to remove zero elements and end up with a vector of non-zero results. Here's an example derived from the code the OP posted (I replaced `function(a,b,c,d)` with `rand()` for the sake of the example):

```
k=15;

for i=1:k:100
    for j=1:k:200
        result(j,i) = rand();
    end
end

result(result == 0) = [];
```

Alternatively, the solution proposed by Cris Luengo generates a matrix that doesn't contain zero elements to start with; I plugged his idea in my sample code:

```
k=15;
for i=1:k:100
  for j=1:k:200
    result((j-1)/k+1, (i-1)/k+1) = rand();
  end
end
```